# FFMPEG: Convert GIF to MP4 whilst keeping transparent (alpha-channel) background

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to compress/convert a GIF file to an MP4 through FFMPEG. All is well but I am trying to figure out a way to preserve the alpha channel rather than the transparency turning to white. The GIF is just a bunch of images that change but they vary in size with a psuedo'd image on the container, so maintaining the transparency is imperative.

Understandably after a long google search, it does seem that MP4 does not support alpha channels. 
I am wondering if anyone would be able to provide a solution on how to create a workaround for this?

The command I am currently running which converts fine but with the white background is :

```
ffmpeg -an -i 2.gif -vf scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt rgba yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 2-test-remade.mp4
```

And I have also tried the command below with no success:

```
 ffmpeg -an lavfi -i color=RRGGBB -i 2.gif -vf scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" \
  -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref[bg][gif];[bg]setsar=1[bg];[bg][gif]overlay=shortest=1" \
-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt rgba yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 2-test-trans.mp4
```

Error message from above command:

```
[color @ 0x7fe49ed19500] Cannot find color 'RRGGBB'
[color @ 0x7fe49ed19500] Unable to parse option value "RRGGBB" as color
[color @ 0x7fe49ed19500] Cannot find color 'RRGGBB'
[color @ 0x7fe49ed19500] Unable to parse option value "RRGGBB" as color
[color @ 0x7fe49ed19500] Error setting option color to value RRGGBB.
[Parsed_color_0 @ 0x7fe49ed19400] Error applying options to the filter.
[lavfi @ 0x7fe4a0009c00] Error initializing filter 'color' with args 'RRGGBB'
color=RRGGBB: Invalid argument
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

**EDIT:**
WebM maintains the alpha channel, but that is already fine. This is to create an MP4 fallback for devices & browsers that do not yet support WebM playback.

Comment: I am not aware of any H.264 or HEVC encoder supported by ffmpeg that has alpha support. However, to answer your question literally, you can mux VP9 (which supports alpha) into MP4, but I doubt that would be helpful as the browsers that don't support webm probably won't support VP9 (one of the video formats common in webm), and who knows if they would support the VP9 alpha in MP4 anyway.

Comment: Yeah, this is the thing I had encountered, had good progress with WebM and the fallback MP4 had unexpected issues haha. Had read somewhere about splitting down the frames as images and combining them back together into an MP4 but assumed the process would no doubt be the same output if H.264 doesn't have alpha control.

Comment: The frames->images->MP4 wouldn't work because in the end the encoder will have to choose a pixel format that it supports, and with libx26* that does not include alpha. You can see supported pixel formats such as with: `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264`. If the encoder supports alpha you would see a pixel format with `a` in the name, such as `yuva420p`, such as with `ffmpeg -h encoder=libvpx-vp9`.

Comment: @llogan yuva420p gives this error and selecting yuv420p automatically. ```Incompatible pixel format 'yuva420p' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'```

Comment: @PravyNandas That's to be expected. libx264 does not support yuva420p, so it will select a pixel format that is supported.